# failure of adb to copy .apk file to the Android Emulator: no such file or directory

Tags: android-emulator

I'm hitting a snag in getting the MyFirstApp (Hello World) Android app to work in the emulator.

I am following the instructions at:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Windows7-64  /  Eclipse

The app works via USB to my phone.

Steps taken:

1. Make sure my PATH environment variable includes the Android SDK.  OK.
2. Launch C:/Users/(me)/AppData/Local/Androd/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe.  OK.
3. Start the emulator from Eclipse. OK, it comes up.
4. Verify that MyFirstApp.apk is present in the Eclipse workspace MyFirstApp/bin directory.
5. Run the MyFirstApp application from Eclipse.

The Eclipse console prints out:

---

> [2012-12-01 23:02:15 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:15 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:15 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:15 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 
>   'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Galaxy_Captivate_2.2'
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:15 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:17 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory     [!!  RED (error) !!]
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:17 - MyFirstApp] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory                               [!!  RED (error) !!]
>
> [2012-12-01 23:02:17 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!                                                                       [!!  RED (error) !!]

I tried   adb install    from a command line:

> adb install MyFirstApp.apk

and got

> failed to copy 'MyFirstApp.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/MyFirstApp.apk': No such file or directory
>
> rm failed for /data/local/tmp/MyFirstApp.apk, No such file or directory

I have not seen this problem reported anywhere else after hours of searching.

If I run

> adb shell

I can see the /data directory.  It appears empty but the permissions are 
drwxrwx--x, which would account for my not being able to see any contents.

So it seems that for some reason the .apk file is not getting copied to the emulator.

One other suspicious thing:   If I run

> adb logcat

then this prints out a list of complaints including,

> E/dalvikvm( 3520): Can't open dex cache '/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex': No such file or directory
>
> ...
>
> W/dalvikvm( 3620): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Android SDK Tools             Rev 21

Android SDK Platform-tools    Rev 16

Android 2.2 (API 8)

SDK Platform                 Rev 3

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Luis for your suggestion.

Indeed, the emulator had not started properly.  It was stuck in the black "A N D R O I D         screen of death".   I learned that the emulator has not fully started until it shows a screen like a normal Android phone.

The directory name was not the problem, I was already using the default C:/Users/... directory, not C:/Program Files.

However, today it works.  I am not entirely certain why it works today and not previously.  Here's what I did:

1. Installed the latest versions of Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform Tools from the SDK Manager.  There's a new version since my first attempt in December 2012.
2. Deleted the directory, C:/Users/[my-username]/.android/avd
3. (from Eclipse) created a new AVD using the default values for Memory Options and internal storage.
4. Launched the emulator from Android Virtual Device Manager via Eclipse.   It is helpful to have the LogCat view open in Eclipse to see a typeout of progress as the emulator kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem.
You can try:
First, you can push the apk package to sdcard:
**adb push test.apk /sdcard/**

then, install apk from sdcard:
**adb shell pm install /sdcard/test.apk**

Hope that can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The `data` directory should have about 20 directories in it, even before you install your app. So, if you find it empty, it's not a problem with your app, but a problem with emulator or sdk instalation.

A commom problem that results in strange behaviors comes from using `spaces` in the directory name where `SDK` is installed.

Try choosing in Eclipe the menu `Window`, `Prefrences`, `Android` and in `SDK Location` instead of:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

type (in 32 bits machine):

```
C:\Progr~1\Android\android-sdk
```

or (in 64 bits machine)

```
C:\Progr~2\Android\android-sdk
```

If this doesn't solves your issue, I suggest to re-install ADT and SDK.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was in bad apk file :). It was damaged.

Just, try to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error today when trying to install onto an emulated device.  It turned out to have no available space, which is why the APK file could not be found (because the push failed but for some reason adb didn't know that and provide an informative error).

It's possible that by creating a new AVD this problem would be "disappear".

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell rm -rR -f /data/local/tmp
```

And then

```
mkdir /data/local/tmp

chmod 777 /data/local/tmp
```

try

```
adb install again
```

of course, you can choose the other permission mode