# Getting protocol failure error while installing apk using adb command in android

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to install an apk on `api level 17` emulator using `adb command`.

adb install Test apk

I am getting following error in response

```
protocol failure
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/Test.apk, No such file or directory
```

Anyone know how to handle this error?

Comment: are you sure that the `path` and the `apk` names are correct? and the `apk` is present in that `path`?

Comment: yes, I have apk on desktop. I cd to desktop and I am running adb from desktop.

Comment: Anyone having any idea how to go about this error?

Comment: Edit your question to include the exact commands you are using to install the app and the response. E.G. `adb install -r MyApp.apk`...`Sucess` (or not in your case!)

Comment: Frequently happens when two or more different ADB version are accessible and running simultaneously. Say,  you have a development ADB and another from a OEM software (Kie for Samsung, others for HTC, Motorola etc.) Try to kill ADB with 'adb kill-service' and immediately upload the APK again.

Comment: Try to put your apk to c:\ or d:\ folder directly and run your cmd as administrator

Comment: Try to follow this steps http://stackoverflow.com/a/14178045/1271424 That man have a similar issue. I think, it's a AVD internal bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that in my workplace the people who were facing this problem have only `read permission` on their computer `USB port` has and not `write permission`. After getting USB write permission from admin the problem is no longer occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Navigate to Settings -> Application settings (location may depend on your device).
Here, check `Install from unknown sources`.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Check the steps related to "Zombie ADB process" and "default ADB port" given in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384414/failed-to-install-myapp-apk-on-device-emulator-5554

Answer (score 1):

You may get some troubles if you have introduced *sharedUserId* in an update of the existing app. Check this [Blog](http://java-hamster.blogspot.de/2010/05/androids-shareduserid.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, eclipse was opened with ADT installed, so when I closed eclipse, the problem was gone.